# how to make vim/vi shift-8 search for keyword with "."

Tags: vim, vi

I have always used vim shift-8 to search for the keyword under the courser. It works fine when keyword is simple i.e. alpha-numeric+underscore. However if there is a "." in the keyword. it only search for parts of the keyword delimited by the "."

Ex: "  a.b  ", if my cursor is on a, then shift-8 will search for "a".

Is there a short cut to search for "a.b" as a whole.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a.b` is not one, but two keywords, because the `.` normally doesn't belong to the set of keyword characters. You have two options:

1. Make `.` a keyword character. Use `:set iskeyword+=.` (Or `:setlocal` for a single buffer only. Also note that some filetype plugins may change that option.) Note that this affect motions like `w`, too, and may cause problems with syntax highlighting.
2. With a plugin like my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320), the `*` command is extended to visual mode. With that, you can select any text (like `a.b` via `viW`), and then search for occurrences via `*`. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins; there are several of them.)

Comment: :set isk+=. works nicely. Is there way to unset it without restarting vim?

Comment: Yes, `:set isk-=.` Or revert to the factory-default value via `:set isk&`

Comment: Thanks. should have thought of that ^.^

Comment: I agree completely with using a [visual star](http://vimawesome.com/?q=visual%20star) style plugin. It is an absolute must in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. According to the manual, "`*`" / "`#`" use a *whole word* for the search, and there is a way to change what `vim` thinks is a word. The variable that contains that setting is `iskeyword`, and it defaults to values like `@,48-57,_,192-255` or `!-~,^*,^|,^",192-255`.

You can print your current setting with one of the following commands

```
:set isk
:set iskeyword
```

Try setting it to something like `@,46,48-57,_,192-255` instead. The important thing is to include *46* in the settings, which is the '`.`' character. The following commands would do the job:

```
:set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
:set isk+=.
```

Answer (score 1):

See the help for `'iskeyword'`:

```
                                                *'iskeyword'* *'isk'*
'iskeyword' 'isk'       string (Vim default for MS-DOS and Win32:
                                            "@,48-57,_,128-167,224-235"
                                   otherwise:  "@,48-57,_,192-255"
                                Vi default: "@,48-57,_")
                        local to buffer
                        {not in Vi}
        Keywords are used in searching and recognizing with many commands:
        "w", "*", "[i", etc.  It is also used for "\k" in a |pattern|.  See
        'isfname' for a description of the format of this option.  For C
        programs you could use "a-z,A-Z,48-57,_,.,-,>".
        For a help file it is set to all non-blank printable characters except
        '*', '"' and '|' (so that CTRL-] on a command finds the help for that
        command).
        When the 'lisp' option is on the '-' character is always included.
        NOTE: This option is set to the Vi default value when 'compatible' is
        set and to the Vim default value when 'compatible' is reset.
```

So, as in the example, you could

```
set isk=a-z,A-Z,48-57,_,.,-,>
```

and <kbd>*</kbd> (and other commands) would include `.` in their definitions of a word.